# i18n angular fails after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, locale, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui bootstrap and use `tmhDynamicLocaleProvider` to get the correct translations for days,month etc in my datepicker.

It works all fine as long as I load the locale documents from online. If I load documents locally (I need to do it locally), it doesn't load the correct translations after minification.

My code looks as follows

```
 app.config(['tmhDynamicLocaleProvider', function(tmhDynamicLocaleProvider) {
      tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('app/datepickerLocale/locale.{{locale}}.js');
  }])

app.config(....{
    $provide.decorator('uibDatepickerDirective', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        angular.forEach($delegate, function (directive) {
          var originalCompile = directive.compile;
          var originalLink = directive.link;
          if (originalCompile) {
            directive.compile = function () {
              return function (scope) {
                scope.$on('$localeChangeSuccess', function () {
                  scope.move(0);
                });
                originalLink.apply(this, arguments);
              };
            }
          }
        });
        return $delegate;
      }]);
})
```

I resolve it in a state

```
.state('main', {
          url: '/{language:[a-z]{2}}',
          templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',

          controller: 'MainCtrl',
          controllerAs: 'mainCtrl',
          resolve: {

            localeLanguage: ['resolveService', '$stateParams', function(resolveService, $stateParams){
              resolveService.resolveLocale($stateParams)
            }]
          }
        })
```

the service looks as follows

```
 resolveLocale: function(stateParams){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if(stateParams.language){
              tmhDynamicLocale.set(stateParams.language);
              deferred.resolve(1);
            } else {
              deferred.resolve(2);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
          }
```

it all works fine until minification. After that I obtain the error, that
the script was not able to be obtained. (GET error).

**I assume that the while invoking the function the script locale.en.js has not been loaded yet. Or am I wrong here?**

How can I solve this?